# How to work with Eclipse adt for Android lollipop development

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

I only have 1GB memory for my computer, 256GB hard disk, I was not able to install Android Studio. I want to work with Eclipse to develop android apps for Android 5.0 or above. Please guide me how can I do so. It would be better if any links are provided for step-by-step tutorial regarding this matter.

I am using "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702". When I tried to setup eclipse with Android Marshmallow I got following error shown in Eclipse

> "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in".

Comment: You won't go far with 1GB RAM on your computer, I think even with eclipse for regular JAVA programming, it is not usable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using adt plugin whoes been updated last time in

> Mon, 2016-11-07 14:20

and [stop being supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)  before [22 API level](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wersje_systemu_Android)
, you can look at [Andmore: Development Tools for Android](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/andmore-development-tools-android%E2%84%A2#group-details) in eclipse marketplace, and been official eclipse project.

Github [project](https://github.com/eclipse/andmore) of Andmore, but it's not even if 1.0v

But you will won't do anything with 1GB memory :/